# Load dynamically created bitmaps with Glide

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide

I want to use Glide on Android just for caching bitmaps. The bitmaps are created dynamically using a Canvas.

I think I should be able to do something like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
  .using(MyCustomBitmapCreator)
  .load((Object) MyCustomBitmapId)
  .into(imageView)
```

I would like Glide to check if the image was cached and if not call MyCustomBitmapCreator to load it. I would really like to stick with Glide since I am already using it to load images from Urls. Does anyone have an example of how this would be done?